# Real World Object Oriented PHP Application

Tags: php, oop

Anyone knows a good tutorial/book/guide for an Object Oriented Application with PHP? I'm not talking about learning OO, I know OO, but I have some difficulties in implementing the concept with Web Development.

It will be good if I can find a real world example including OOP, PHP, MySQL, Sessions(logins, shopping carts,...), etc.

Comment: Please, use a search engine :(

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at the source code of PHP frameworks.  Zend, CodeIgnitor, etc. Also read the usages.  It'll give you an idea of how OOP Lamp stack can work.

Comment: Grab one and start trying to make something in it, and you'll learn as you go :)